# org.hibernate.QueryException - could not resolve property

Tags: hibernate, mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to connect using Hibernate to a database. This current table has the following layout:

```
(field1, field2, field3, optional1, optional2...)
```

where field1, field2, field3 are all foreign keys, and together make up a composite key.

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "db_table_mainRecords")
public class MainRecord implements Serializable{
    @EmbeddedId
    private MainRecordKey   lqk;
    @Transient
    private String          field1;
    @Transient
    private int         field2;
    @Transient
    private int         field3;
    @Column(name = "optional_1")
    private double          optional1;
    @Column(name = "optional_2")
    private double          optional2;

....
  // Getters and setters for all fields, including fields within MainClassKey
....
}
```

And this accompanying it:

```
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "db_table_mainRecords")
public class MainRecordKey implements Serializable{
    @Column(name = "field1")
    private String field_1; 
    @Column(name = "field_2")
    private int field2;
    @Column(name = "field_3")
    private int field3;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException - could not resolve property: field3 of: path.MainRecord at  org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:67)

Here is my Bo /dao code:

```
public List<MainRecord> getMainRecords(int e){
    Criterion crit1 = Restrictions.eq("field3", e);
    ArrayList<MainRecord> list = (ArrayList<MainRecord>) dao.getMainRecords(crit1);
}


public List<MainRecord> getMainRecords(Criterion criteria){
    if(criteria == null)
        return new ArrayList<MainReocrd>();
    return (List<MainRecord>) getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(DetachedCriteria.forClass(MainRecord.class).add(criteria));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to change all `int` to `Integer` and `double` to `Double` in your mapping files `MainRecord` and `MainRecordKey`.

**UPDATE**
Try this:

```
Restrictions.eq("lqk.field3", e);
```

Comment: This is so aggravating.